# Taylor series $\sqrt{z+i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

could you please help me to develop the following serial function of taylor, i can't find the pattern of the nth derivatives, i would appreciate it very much:

$\sqrt{z+i}$

I've dealt with common series development, but I don't know if there will be any tricks or something like that

Comment: $\sqrt{z+i}=\sqrt{i}\left(1+\frac zi\right)^{1/2}$

Comment: [Answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+expansion+sqrt%28z%2Bi%29)

Comment: the thing is I need development ... but I can't find a formula for the nth derivative

Comment: About what point?

Comment: About the point z=0